# Python - Lookup a value in the dataframe for the same ID

Tags: python, regex, pandas, numpy

I have the following dataframe as shown below

```
ID    TYPE    POLICY_NUMBER       DISB_AMT
738   20      FLDINC MSH39990     1
738   21      MSH39990            3848
750   20      INF395737           1
750   21      INF395737 FLDINCL   2350
892   20      SJK389743           3904
892   21      MSH284989           1
```

I'm trying to group by the ID and extract the policy number and search in the other TYPE eg:(TYPE =20 or 21) if the policy number is same in both TYPE for an ID then check if DISB_AMT>1 in the two rows. If true then do not append this to the dataframe.

eg: ID 738 has the same policy number MSH39990 in both rows. I wrote a script to extract only numbers so that it is easier to compare. ID 738 has the same policy number. Now we check if the DISB_AMT > 1. In the first row it is not >1. In the second row we have 3848>1. Do not include this ID in the result. For ID 892 since the POLICY NUMBER is not same in both TYPE we check only if DISB_AMT>1 for TYPE 21. Since it is not >1 we add this row to the results dataframe.

How do I compare it with the other type and check if the policy number is the same and build the rest of the logic?

**Expected Output**

```
ID    TYPE    POLICY_NUMBER       DISB_AMT
892   21      MSH284989           1
```

**Code**

```
data = [{"ID":738,"TYPE":20,"POLICY_NUMBER":"FLDINC MSH39990","DISB_AMT":1},
        {"ID":738,"TYPE":21,"POLICY_NUMBER":"MSH39990","DISB_AMT":3848},
        {"ID":750,"TYPE":20,"POLICY_NUMBER":"INF395737","DISB_AMT":1},
        {"ID":750,"TYPE":21,"POLICY_NUMBER":"INF395737 FLDINCL","DISB_AMT":2350},
        {"ID":892,"TYPE":20,"POLICY_NUMBER":"SJK389743","DISB_AMT":3904},
        {"ID":892,"TYPE":21,"POLICY_NUMBER":"MSH284989","DISB_AMT":1}
        ]

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

df['CLEANED_POL_NBR']=df.POLICY_NUMBER.str.extract('(\d+)')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
df[~df.duplicated(['ID','CLEANED_POL_NBR'], keep=False) & df['DISB_AMT'].eq(1)]
```

Output:

```
   DISB_AMT   ID POLICY_NUMBER  TYPE CLEANED_POL_NBR
5         1  892     MSH284989    21          284989
```

Comment: If the policy numbers match then we check the DISB_AMT in both types (20 or 21). If the policy numbers do not match we check for TYPE=21 if the DISB_AMT=1. How can I add this one additional filter i.e TYPE=21 when policy don't match?